# CakePHP - query returns empty field if it has a special character in it

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have what I think to be a normal query-call in CakePHP - it works for all results, but when a field has a special character in it, the field will return empty.  It doesn't break - and it still gives me the rest of the fields - it's just that one field that's empty.

Example:

```
$this->paginate = array(
'conditions' => array(
     'Item.name != ' => '',
),
);
$data = $this->paginate('Item');
```

This will return all the items in my table (including the one that I thought had an empty name field) - but when I try to echo the name to the page, it works for every item except the one with a special character (é).  I changed it to a normal "e" and it shows up fine.

How can I return results even if they have a special character in their name?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the encoding of the table? Also, what happens when you run the query manually, does it show up? And check whether the field is actually populated by running a `var_dump()` on it

Comment: @JohnP - I'm not sure about the encoding, but when I run the query manually (in software or via regular php), it shows up just fine.

Comment: @Dave you'll need to confirm whether Cake's running any filtering on the data. Run a var_dump() or debug() and see whether the data is actually present in the array and just not displaying. You might also want to set the DB's collation to utf_8 as well as the content-type in the HTML

Comment: Use Item.name != utf8_decode('countryname')... and it will work

Comment: @Sudhir - how can I use utf8_decode in a mysql query?

Comment: If you want to get a good answer you need to provide more data: 1. What is the encoding of your database table? 2. Post the query that is produced by cake. 3. What is the default value for `name` column? Null or empty string? Is it allowed to be null?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check to make sure your database uses the right encoding (UTF-8, ideally) and you have configured Cake to use this same encoding as well in `config/database.php`:

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {
    public $default = array(
        ...
        'encoding' => 'utf8'
    );
}
```

If you have some encoding mismatch, your app has probably stored garbage in the database already, so make sure you test with the right data and/or a fresh database.

Comment: Will UTF-8 allow me to keep special characters like umlaut-letters...etc?

Comment: Plus - the content in the database looks fine - it has the special characters correct and everything

Comment: Yes, UTF-8 allows you to store and handle virtually any human character correctly. How are you confirming the contents of your database? You may actually be looking at garbage twice incorrectly handled, which would display it correctly again.

Comment: I'm just looking at it in Navicat.  Is that not ok?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably less of a Cake-specific issue and more of a PHP / MySQL issue. (Others have already brought up encoding, so I'll skip that.)

Single quotes means a literal string being handed to MySQL: `'Item.name != ' => ''`

PHP (a la Cake) probably parses that string quite literally. In fact, it's might even be parsing it like:

```
"Item.name != "
```

(note there's nothing after the operand? and if it falls last in the SQL query, the query wouldn't error, it would probably still work!)

When you meant for it to test:

```
"Item.name != ''"
```

(note empty single quotes now included in the string)

However, since you're not getting an error - and the rest of the data pulls! - you probably want to edit that statement, because your problem is more likely syntax.

```
'Item.name IS NOT NULL'
'Item.name <> ' => ''
'Item.name IS NOT' => ''
```

Give those a try.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html describing IS NOT NULL vs IS NOT (bool) vs <> and != (is not equal to).

HTH :)