# Cannot retrieve data from find query

Tags: cakephp-2.x

In my Event model, I have the following function to retrieve all the events with status = 1 with a 12 limit and order according to event created DESC:

```
public function latestEvents() {
    $this->Behaviors->load('Containable');
    $result = $this->find('all' ,array('recursive' => -1, 'conditions'=> array('Event.status' => 1), 'limit' => 12, 'order' => array('Event.created DESC')));
    debug($result); die();
    return $result;
}
```

This function is not returning any data. When I change my limit to 6 and debug it returns six records but when I change my limit to more than 6 it returns (empty) this :
[image]

I even checked in my database by doing this query :

```
SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `status` = 1 ORDER BY `created` DESC LIMIT 12
```

and this returns the desired data that I want. I even tried :

```
$result = $this->query('SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `status` = 1 ORDER BY `created` DESC LIMIT 12');
```

but the same thing is happening with the limit (6 returns the data but more than 6 does not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the data I was trying to debug had special characters and I had to include `'encoding' => 'utf8'` in my database.php and worked like a charm. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610123/cakephp-query-returns-empty-field-if-it-has-a-special-character-in-it) helped me.